# Почему не сохраняет в csv иконки вставленые в QTableWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

```
def save_file(self):
fs = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Сохранить', '', 'CSV(*.csv)')
if fs:
    with open(fs, 'w') as stream:
        writer = csv.writer(stream)
        for x in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            row = []
            for y in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                item = self.table.item(x, y)
                if item is not None:
                    row.append(item.text())
                    print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что в QTableWidget у вас в каких-то ячейках изображения, а в файл csv они не сохраняются? Вообще, csv - текстовый формат, никакие данные кроме текста туда не сохранятся.

Comment: А не подскажете в каком можно формате сохранить?

Comment: Например xls, xlsx, ods.

Comment: ну, иконки можно сохранить в csv, но нужно будет вручную их конвертировать в base64 (или подобный ему формат)